# JQ Split JSON in several files

Tags: json, file, jq, partition

I'm new on this. And trying to spare or split a JSON in several files according to the content.
The "name" of the target group is "root_rgs" and I'd like to have it in different files each one.

```
{
  "root_rgs": [
    "PROM_FD_ARCNA",
    "PROM_JOB_ICMP"
  ],
  "targets": [
    "HCC02155",
    "HCC09350",
    "HCC09321",
    "HCCEFACTORYWWW",
    "HCC9723"
  ]
}
{
  "root_rgs": [
    "PROM_FD_ARCNA",
    "PROM_JOB_WIN"
  ],
  "targets": [
    "LABTNSARWID236",
    "LABTNSARWID692",
    "VM00006"
  ]
}
{
  "root_rgs": [
    "PROM_FD_MTZ",
    "PROM_JOB_ICMP"
  ],
  "targets": [
    "TEIARWIN205",
    "TEIARWDB150",
    "TEIARWCXWA212"
  ]
}
```

Is it possible to generate something like:

`ARCNA_ICMP.json`

```
{
TARGETS:
        "HCC02155",
        "HCC09350",
        "HCC09321",
        "HCCEFACTORYWWW",
        "HCC9723"
}
```

---

`ARCNA_WIN.json`

```
{
TARGETS:
    "LABTNSARWID236",
    "LABTNSARWID692",
    "VM00006"
}
```

---

And so on...

Hope to be clear, thanks everyone!

Comment: Re "*Hope to be clear*", Start by giving valid JSON for your expected output. You say you want JSON output but provide something that's not even close to valid JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possibility would be to combine one invocation of jq with one invocation of a utility like `awk` for writing the files:

```
jq -cr '(.root_rgs | "\(.[0]|sub("PROM_FD_";""))\(.[1]|sub("PROM_JOB";""))"),
        {TARGETS: .targets}' input.json |
  awk 'NR%2==1 {fn = $1 ".json"; next} {print $0 >> fn}'
```

Of course, the resultant files will not, in general, be pretty-printed.

WARNING: the above appends to existing files.  In practice, an alternative method of handling such files would probably be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

jq itself cannot write to files, neither to one nor to many. The shell calling jq, however, can. Therefore, any solution needs to orchestrate these two levels by splitting up the task into parts and have each carried out by one of the two levels (or any third party tool).

One straightforward way could be to employ jq to separate the stream into documents and prepare them to already carry the file's name and content, and iterate in the shell over that output. Then, with each iteration step, jq can be used again to extract that data and have the shell save the content to a file.

```sh
jq -c '{
  name: "\(.root_rgs | map(split("_")[-1]) | join("_")).json",
  content: {targets}
}' input.json | while read -r json; do
  jq '.content' <<< "$json" > "$(jq -r '.name' <<< "$json")"
done
```

Another way could be to have jq generate a script that is executable in the shell. This would reduce the number of times jq has to be called from 2n+1 to just 1, which can be important if the input file contains many docuemnts.

```sh
jq -r '"cat"
  + " >\(.root_rgs | map(split("_")[-1]) | join("_")).json"
  + " <<<\({targets} | tojson | @sh)"
' input.json | bash
```

This produces for each document in the input stream a line of the form `cat >FILENAME <<<'JSON'` which instructs the shell to `cat` to a file its input, which in turn is provided as a [Here String](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html) which is understood by `bash`, to which the commands are piped eventually.